# How are n dimensional vectors state vectors represented in Q Learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

Using this code:

```
import gym
import numpy as np
import time

"""
SARSA on policy learning python implementation.
This is a python implementation of the SARSA algorithm in the Sutton and Barto's book on
RL. It's called SARSA because - (state, action, reward, state, action). The only difference
between SARSA and Qlearning is that SARSA takes the next action based on the current policy
while qlearning takes the action with maximum utility of next state.
Using the simplest gym environment for brevity: https://gym.openai.com/envs/FrozenLake-v0/
"""

def init_q(s, a, type="ones"):
    """
    @param s the number of states
    @param a the number of actions
    @param type random, ones or zeros for the initialization
    """
    if type == "ones":
        return np.ones((s, a))
    elif type == "random":
        return np.random.random((s, a))
    elif type == "zeros":
        return np.zeros((s, a))


def epsilon_greedy(Q, epsilon, n_actions, s, train=False):
    """
    @param Q Q values state x action -> value
    @param epsilon for exploration
    @param s number of states
    @param train if true then no random actions selected
    """
    if train or np.random.rand() < epsilon:
        action = np.argmax(Q[s, :])
    else:
        action = np.random.randint(0, n_actions)
    return action

def sarsa(alpha, gamma, epsilon, episodes, max_steps, n_tests, render = True, test=False):
    """
    @param alpha learning rate
    @param gamma decay factor
    @param epsilon for exploration
    @param max_steps for max step in each episode
    @param n_tests number of test episodes
    """
    env = gym.make('Taxi-v3')
    n_states, n_actions = env.observation_space.n, env.action_space.n
    Q = init_q(n_states, n_actions, type="ones")
    print('Q shape:' , Q.shape)

    timestep_reward = []
    for episode in range(episodes):
        print(f"Episode: {episode}")
        total_reward = 0
        s = env.reset()
        print('s:' , s)
        a = epsilon_greedy(Q, epsilon, n_actions, s)
        t = 0
        done = False
        while t < max_steps:
            if render:
                env.render()
            t += 1
            s_, reward, done, info = env.step(a)
            total_reward += reward
            a_ = epsilon_greedy(Q, epsilon, n_actions, s_)
            if done:
                Q[s, a] += alpha * ( reward  - Q[s, a] )
            else:
                Q[s, a] += alpha * ( reward + (gamma * Q[s_, a_] ) - Q[s, a] )
            s, a = s_, a_
            if done:
                if render:
                    print(f"This episode took {t} timesteps and reward {total_reward}")
                timestep_reward.append(total_reward)
                break
#             print('Updated Q values:' , Q)
    if render:
        print(f"Here are the Q values:\n{Q}\nTesting now:")
    if test:
        test_agent(Q, env, n_tests, n_actions)
    return timestep_reward

def test_agent(Q, env, n_tests, n_actions, delay=0.1):
    for test in range(n_tests):
        print(f"Test #{test}")
        s = env.reset()
        done = False
        epsilon = 0
        total_reward = 0
        while True:
            time.sleep(delay)
            env.render()
            a = epsilon_greedy(Q, epsilon, n_actions, s, train=True)
            print(f"Chose action {a} for state {s}")
            s, reward, done, info = env.step(a)
            total_reward += reward
            if done:  
                print(f"Episode reward: {total_reward}")
                time.sleep(1)
                break


if __name__ =="__main__":
    alpha = 0.4
    gamma = 0.999
    epsilon = 0.9
    episodes = 200
    max_steps = 20
    n_tests = 20
    timestep_reward = sarsa(alpha, gamma, epsilon, episodes, max_steps, n_tests)
    print(timestep_reward)
```

from :

https://towardsdatascience.com/reinforcement-learning-temporal-difference-sarsa-q-learning-expected-sarsa-on-python-9fecfda7467e

A sample Q table generated is :

```
[[ 1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.        ]
 [ 0.5996      0.5996      0.5996      0.35936     0.5996      1.        ]
 [ 0.19936016  0.35936     0.10336026  0.35936     0.35936    -5.56063984]
 ...
 [ 0.35936     0.5996      0.35936     0.5996      1.          1.        ]
 [ 1.          0.5996      1.          1.          1.          1.        ]
 [ 0.35936     0.5996      1.          1.          1.          1.        ]]
```

The columns representing the actions and rows representing the corresponding states.

Can the state be represented by a vector ? The Q table cells are not contained by vectors of size > 1 so how should these states be represented ? For example if I'm in state [2] can this be represented as an n dimensional vector ?

Put another way if Q[1,3] = 4 can the Q state 1 with action 3 be represented as vector[1,3,2,12,3] ? If so then is the state_number->state_attributes mapping stored in a separate lookup table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, states can be represented by anything you want, including vectors of arbitrary length. Note, however, that if you are using a tabular version of Q-learning (or SARSA as in this case), you must have a discrete set of states. Therefore, you need a way to map the representation of your state (for example, a vector of potentially continuous values) to a set of discrete states.

Expanding on the example you have given, imagine that you have three states represented by vectors:

```
s0 = [1, 3, 2, 12, 3]
s1 = [3, 1, 2, 2, 23]
s2 = [2, 12, 3, 2, 1]
```

In the end, you only have 3 states, regardless of how they are represented. You could map the vectors to the states `s0`, `s1` and `s2`, and use a simple Q-table. Or you can use other data structures that use vector representation (i.e. `[1, 3, 2, 12, 3]`) as an index.

On the other hand, if your state space is continuous and you don't want to discretize it, then you can use function approximators (e.g., a neural network) to store Q values instead of a table. But that's another topic (more info in chapter 8 of [Sutton & Barto RL book](http://incompleteideas.net/book/bookdraft2017nov5.pdf)).

Comment: thanks for this . I would also want to use a  function approximator if the size of the discrete space if large - for example use an auto-encoder to reduce the dimensionality of each state vector. I don't fully understand using the vector representation as an index - in your example : [1, 3, 2, 12, 3] would s0 be stored at array positions - [1] , [3], [2], [12], [3] ? Can you elaborate on this as I don't understand "can use other data structures that use vector representation (i.e. [1, 3, 2, 12, 3]) as an index." Other than a Q-table I'm not aware of other mechanisms to store the vector states.

Comment: Exactly, just take into account that using function approximators changes the convergence properties of Q-learning an other algorithms, so maybe it's necessary to use some "tricks" to improve stability (e.g. experience replay). Regarding the example, I have nothing specific in mind. I guess there exist some key-value structures where you can use vector-based keys. In a very naive approach, in Python, you can use the string "1, 3, 2, 12, 3" as a dictionary key (although I'm not sure is the best solution).